# I am Trying to replace Double quotes in a string with single quote by querying in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have two queries for doing so,they are as follows:

```
SELECT someString
      ,replace(someString, Char(34), char(39)) as replacedString
FROM   (SELECT concat(' abc ' , Char(34) ,' def ') as someString) as x
```

Above Query works fine and i get the desired results.

However, in second query i don't get the desired results

```
Declare @var varchar(10)='ab''''cd' 
select @var,REPLACE(@var,char(34),char(39)) as RepVAR
```

Second query fails to replace double quotes with single quotes and i am unable to figure out the reason for it.

Comment: That was good McNets

Comment: Can we see desired resault?

Comment: There are no double quotes in `@var`, only four single quotes. `char(34)` is a single character, `"`, not two characters, `''`. Maybe you could tell us exactly what you are trying to do, rather than how you've decided to do it...

Comment: Mybe you mean ab' 'cd --> ab" "cd

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering.

Answer (score 0):

There are no double quotes in `@Var` So you will get the same `@var` try:

```
Declare @var varchar(10)='ab''''cd' 
select @var,REPLACE(@var,char(39),char(34)) as RepVAR
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server strings are surrounded by single quotes (`'`). 
To put a single quote within a string, you use two single quotes.

```
'Why doesn''t this work?'
```

If you want two single quotes, then each of them must be written as two single quotes.

```
'abc''''def'
```

So this string is `abc`, followed by two single quotes, followed by `def`.
But two single quotes are not the same as a double quote (`"`).
If you want a string with a double quote, simply write the double quote character.

```
'abc"def'
```